# Horizontal CSS skew in Firefox blurs box element vertically

Tags: css, firefox, skew, blurry

I am finding that applying a `transform:skewX()` to an element blurs its poition vertically(!) in Firefox. Does anyone know why, or how to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="tab"><span>Tab</span></div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tab {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2em;
    position: relative;
    width: 3em;
    text-align:center;
    padding: .375em 0 0.125em;
}
#tab span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#tab:before,
#tab:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #999999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
}
#tab:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    border-left: 2px solid #999999;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
#tab:after {
    right: 0;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    border-right: 2px solid #999999;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
#content {
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 0px;    
}
```

The result is as below (zoomed image). Note the #content box's border showing through where they don't overlap, and the fuzziness at the top of the tab (both above and below the 2px width). By comparrison, when removing the `skewX()` for a straight tab, the border becomes pixel-perfect.

[image: Enlarged screenshot of tab with skew, and without, to show vertical blurring]

Is there any way to force the element's vertical pixel-alignment when it is subjected to a skewX() transform?